# Query for page recommendations

Tags: sql

I have two tables in my PieCloudDB database, one table records the user's friend relationship, and the other table records the user's favorite page ID.

| user1_id | user2_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 1 |

| user_id | page_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 28 |
| 2 | 66 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 49 |
| 4 | 32 |
| 5 | 8 |
| 6 | 28 |
| 6 | 49 |

If a page is liked by at least one of the user's friends, but the user himself does not like it, then the page will be recommended to this user.

Now I need a solution to find all possible page recommendations for every user.

The results of example data should be:

| user_id | page_id | likes_numbers |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | 49 | 2 |
| 1 | 66 | 1 |
| 2 | 8 | 1 |
| 2 | 28 | 1 |
| 3 | 8 | 1 |
| 3 | 28 | 1 |
| 3 | 32 | 1 |
| 4 | 5 | 1 |
| 4 | 28 | 1 |
| 4 | 49 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 49 | 1 |
| 5 | 66 | 1 |
| 6 | 32 | 1 |

User 1 is friends with users 2, 3, and 6.
Recommended pages are 5(user 3 liked it), 49(**both** user 3 and user 6 liked it),66(user 2 liked it).
Note that page 28 is not recommended because user 1 already liked it.

`likes_numbers` means number of friends who like this page.

The following is my query, I can get the right anwser but the execution time is too long(especially when the data becomes larger). I want to make a better perfomance, can anyone give me some advice?

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.user1_id AS user_id, l.page_id, COUNT(*) AS likes_numbers
FROM (
    SELECT user1_id, user2_id
    FROM Friendship
    UNION
    SELECT user2_id, user1_id
    FROM Friendship
) f
JOIN likes l ON f.user2_id = l.user_id
WHERE f.user1_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM likes WHERE user_id = f.user1_id AND page_id = l.page_id)
GROUP BY f.user1_id, l.page_id
```

Comment: Does every "friend" relationship also have the inverse relationship stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT f.user1_id AS user_id, l.page_id, COUNT(*) AS likes_numbers
FROM (
    SELECT user1_id, user2_id
    FROM Friendship
    UNION
    SELECT user2_id, user1_id
    FROM Friendship
) f
JOIN likes l ON f.user2_id = l.user_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM likes lK 
                   WHERE f.user1_id = LK.user_id AND LK.page_id = l.page_id)
GROUP BY f.user1_id, l.page_id;
```

OR You have another option to use `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT f.user1_id AS user_id, l.page_id, COUNT(*) AS likes_numbers
FROM (
    SELECT user1_id, user2_id
    FROM Friendship
    UNION
    SELECT user2_id, user1_id
    FROM Friendship
) f
JOIN likes l ON f.user2_id = l.user_id
LEFT JOIN likes lK ON f.user1_id = LK.user_id AND LK.page_id = l.page_id
WHERE LK.user_id IS NULL
GROUP BY f.user1_id, l.page_id;
```